# jQuery DataTables sort by checkbox with n columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, checkbox, datatable

I'm using the jQuery plugin DataTables to sort tables throughout my site. There are several tables which utilize a check-all checkbox in the header, and a checkbox in each row. Looking at the documentation and plugins, it seems the best course of action is to utilize this plugin: http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/custom-data-source/dom-checkbox

To implement, it requires the columns option to be used:

```
$('.dt-check').dataTable( {
    "columns": [
        { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
});
```

My problem is that the numerous tables have different counts of columns, meaning I'd need an additional script for every single different table. Is there a way to implement this where I can sort by the first column, regardless of how many columns there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late, but if you haven't solved this problem already, you can set the column on which to sort by using the "columnDefs" property:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderDataType

In your case, if you wanted to order by the first column at all times, you would do this:

```
$('.dt-check').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
        { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox", targets: 0 }
    ]
});
```

I believe the columns are 0 index based, so this setting would apply the dom-checkbox ordering rule to the first column regardless of the column count.